# how can I display output from a JS loop on a HTML page

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am trying to get a user input to display the amount of rows they would like of "+++".
I have tried a lot of things and nothing is working!!! I am currently using document.getElementById('square').innerHTML = text; ,  as my code to display it but nothing is happening, I am also not getting any error messages in my console. Please help!!!

```js
function loop4(){
    var rows = +prompt ('Please enter the ammount of rows you would like')
    var num = 0
    var text = ''
        while (num !==rows){
            text+= '+++ \n';
            num +=1;
        }
     document.getElementById('square').innerHTML = text;
```

```html
        <input class='button' id='square' type='button' onclick="loop4()" value='Draw Square' /> <br>
```

Comment: I'm getting some error messages in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it up, and added a bit too :)

You were missing a parentheses at the end of the function. Additionally, the input element won't take `.innerHTML`. You can set `.value` if you want it to be on the button, but buttons can't take `.innerHTML`.

```js
function loop4() {
  var rows = +prompt('Please enter the ammount of rows you would like')
  var num = 0
  var text = ''
  while (num !== rows) {
    text += '+'.repeat(rows) +' <br>';
    num += 1;
  }
  document.getElementById('square').innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<input class='button' id='square-btn' type='button' onclick="loop4()" value='Draw Square' /> <br>
<pre id="square">

</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the text inside of an element like pre

```js
function loop4(){
    var rows = +prompt ('Please enter the ammount of rows you would like')
    var num = 0
    var text = ''
        while (num !==rows){
            text+= '+++ \n';
            num +=1;
        }
     document.getElementById('square').innerText = text;
}
```

```html
<input class='button' type='button' onclick="loop4()" value='Draw Square' /> <br>

<pre id="square"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could take the following approach, by adding unique DOM elements per row. For each row, you'd populate the `innerHTML` field with your '+++' characters.

Consider the following:

```js
function loop4(){
    var rows = +prompt ('Please enter the ammount of rows you would like')
    var num = 0;

    while (num !==rows){
        num +=1;

        // Create this row's div element
        var row = document.createElement('div');

        // Populate row with + characters
        row.innerHTML = '+++';

        // Add the row to a display area div, which is a new div intended
        // for displaying the desired result
        document.getElementById('square').append( row );
    }

} // Also, be sure to add this to avoid syntax errors
```

```html
<!-- Remove id=square from button -->
<input class='button' type='button' onclick="loop4()" value='Draw Square' /> <br>

<!-- Add this div to display square -->
<div id="square"></div>
```